# How to get type of enum item?

Tags: c++

A newbie question here...

How to make a tuple type where an item of the tuple is a specific item of an `enum`?

```cpp
enum class MyEnum
{
  MyEnum_FirstItem
};

typedef std::tuple<int, MyEnum::MyEnum_FirstItem> MyTuple; // constant "MyEnum::MyEnum_FirstItem" is not a type name
```

How do I get a type, rather than a value of an enum item?

P.S. Googled with "get enum item type" but found nothing.

I came from TypeScript and I used to do that there for documentation purposes. Also, the real question probably should be: Are there any exact number types at all in c++?

Comment: Just like a class, it's name is its type.

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you need an enum *value* as the type?` It seems to me like `std::tuple` isn't the correct choice here.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Are you trying to make a tuple whose second parameter can only have the value `MyEnum_FirstItem`?

Comment: @Sneftel Yes, exactly

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Please see the above comment

Comment: All enum values in one enum are of the same type.

Comment: If the second value in the tuple is always the same, why store it at all?

Comment: @PaulSanders It's for documentation purposes... I came from TypeScript and I used to do that there...

Comment: Again, what is the *actual* problem you need to solve? *Why* do you need to store the value as a type? Right now this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you ask for help with a solution to an for us unknown problem. Please ask about the *actual* problem instead, and show us the solution (this) you have tried.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the X is documentation purposes, please see the updated question

Comment: _"for documentation purposes"_ is not really a good description of your goal.

Comment: `template<typename Y, Y N> struct foo{};` is an exact number type. E.g. `foo<int, 3> f;`. No doubt the C++ standard library has a similar abstraction.

Comment: @Bathsheba It does; see my answer :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Nice. Have an upvote. Would be even better if my attempt was a suggested implementation ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to get type of enum item?

The type of `MyEnum_FirstItem` is `MyEnum`. Enumerators don't have distinct types.

(However, keep reading…)

---

> What are you trying to do here? Are you trying to make a tuple whose second parameter can only have the value MyEnum_FirstItem? – Sneftel 3 mins ago
>
> @Sneftel Yes, exactly – Nurbol Alpysbayev 2 mins ago

> Are there any exact number types at all in c++?

Actually, yes.

`std::integral_constant<int, 3>` is a *type* representing the `int` value 3. It's used in template metaprogramming.

Perhaps you can do something with that. Because, although `MyEnum_FirstItem` isn't *of* its own type, you can wrap it up to produce such a thing, like this:

```
std::integral_constant<MyEnum, MyEnum::MyEnum_FirstItem>
```

So perhaps:

```
std::tuple<int, std::integral_constant<MyEnum, MyEnum::MyEnum_FirstItem>> MyTuple;
```

([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant))

---

I'd guess that the purpose of this enum is as a "tag" to discriminate various otherwise-identical tuple types, for documentation purposes (and to prevent "cross-contamination" in your codebase too).

If so, I would actually just create a bunch of empty `struct`s for the job, as we would for other tagging implementations.

```
struct TagA {};
struct TagB {};

std::tuple<int, TagA> MyTuple;
```

It's much easier to use and to read, and you can still bung them into a namespace if you want.

Comment: Prefixes on enumerators of `enum class`es seem extremely redundant. Also, will that conversion even work? `MyConstrainedEnum_FirstItem = MyEnum_FirstItem`

Comment: This is the answer I wanted really, I mean that you are caring of my actual question, not my reasons. However I can't say c++ has elegant solution for it :) I thought it has, unlike TypeScript...

Comment: @underscore_d Regarding the prefix, I agree but that wasn't me. Regarding the conversion, I addressed that.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Do check the update - I think what you want is possible, even if I don't really agree you should be doing it (but we don't know your goal so who knows!)

Comment: Actually I might just take out the middle part now - what do we think?

Comment: Wow... Thank you Sir, I am glad that there are people like you on SO. This is exactly what I needed (and that's a pity my question has generated so much hate, instead of something constructive like your answer)

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Downvotes are not hate. Don't take it as such. People might've just found your question unclear.

Comment: @SombreroChicken There is always this problem: I can make it really clear, but no one wants to read and comprehend it. You know, bikeshedding?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev there is zero hate in this post. Comments come off as rude sometimes, but thats  just because ppl try to be to the point. And dont make the mistake to interpret too much into votes. They are rather unpredictable and rather illogical sometimes

Comment: To be fair your initial question was not just an XY question but also based on a false premise, and still doesn't actually explain what you're trying to do. But with a few tidbits from edits and from the comments, we got there in the end.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll take that into account (will explain better my original problems), thank you!

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev I've just added one final edit after a little further thought.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit YES! Your last guess is 100% correct (my English is poor unfortunately to explain in such terms). And I like the struct approach (and I do need to put them in a namespace, though I don't know yet how). I thought structs are heavy (like objects in JS where I came from), but tested just now: they are only 1 byte? Wow, that's a surprise. Another reason to thank you!

Comment: Ahh, nope, I can't use structs, I forgot that the tuples I am making represent data interexchange format (with JS, I am writing a Node.js addon). But, still this technique is very helpful for other cases in the future! (sorry for bothering SO much, just documenting :-) )

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Yes completely lightweight and probably smaller than your integral constant! It would be zero bytes if it weren't for the fact that all objects must take up _some_ space (so that addresses are unique)

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing types with instances of that type. `MyEnum` is a type, `MyEnum::MyEnum_FirstItem` is an instance of that type. Try

```
typedef std::tuple<int, MyEnum> MyTuple;
```

Then later you can have `MyEnum::MyEnum_FirstItem` as second value in a `MyTuple`.

Just to reiterate...

> P.S. Googled with "get enum item type" but found nothing..

The type of `MyEnum::MyEnum_FirstItem` is `MyEnum`.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I don't........

Comment: @Ventu can you eloborate? I did realize that substantial clarification has been provided in comments, but for the question as it stands this is quite relvant (even though it does maybe not adress what OP actually had in mind)

Comment: @Ventu I mean I even quote from the question and directly relate to it. "nothing to do with the question" ... sorry I shouldnt have taken this serious...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me a little to fix things in my head. I realize my question lacks more explanation, but you'd probably agree the other answer is just on point.